# This is caused me typescript cannot read property of undefined (reading 'domain')

Tags: typescript, filter

** This is caused me typescript cannot read property of undefined (reading 'domain')**

This is caused me typescript cannot read property of undefined (reading 'domain')
how to solve this problem

This is json object

```
[
  {
    "cnl":1233,
    "record": [
      {
        "querName": "style-Query",
        "data":{
          "name":"james"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is data model

```
export interface cnlModel{
  id:string,
  user:string,
  record:[
    querName:string
  ]
}
```

this is the html

```
<div>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "cnlDataFilter">
<button (click)= "getDataByCnl()">search </button>
</div>

<div *ngIf= "filterreddata">
show data
</div>
```

This component.ts is the code for the filter method by using Type script

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './plm.component.html',
})
private _cnlDataFilter = '';

set cnlDataFilter (value:string)
{
   this._cnlDataFilter = value;
}

get cnlDataFilter(){
  return this._cnlDataFilter;
}

public getDataByCnl()
{
  this.plmService.getCnlData(this._cnlDataFilter).subscribe({
    next:(data) => {
      this.filterreddata = data;

      const modified = this.filterreddata.map(function(ComparisonResult) {
        ComparisonResult.record = ComparisonResult.record.filter(x => x.querName === "style-Query");
        return ComparisonResult;
      });
      console.log(modified)

      let and = this.filterreddata.filter((I:any)=>i.querName === "style-Query")
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're using an object in your template that is undefined and therefore its `domain` property cannot be read. Could you add your template code as well?

Comment: You most likely need to add `*ngIf` or use safe navigation operator `xxx?.domain` (probably better) in the template. This happens if the object is not yet loaded (e.g. async http request) when the template is first evaluated.

Comment: @AldinBradaric I didn't get you what template (this Angular template is already defined) in my code and it's working

Comment: @GunnarB. How can we add *ngIf in type script it is Angular ? am l correct

Comment: When I say template, I am referring to your html file. Unless you're defining your html inside your ts file.

Comment: Please add the code, that accesses the domain property

Comment: @AldinBradaric I add the html

Comment: Do you access `domain` somwhere in the block where you say `show data`? Because currently the spot that is throwing your error is nowhere in the code that you provided. And, with template I also referred to the html file (template is the common name for that).

Comment: Usually your IDE will indicate what file is throwing the error. Because right now it looks like it might be your `plmService`. There is no other reference to `domain` in your provided html or code.